# React life cycle method for making API call when component is re-rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a component called `<Header>` where I have a log-in form that makes an API call to log a user in.

I have a function in my header component that makes some API calls to fetch some data and update the menu items in the header once successfully logged in:

```
componentDidMount() {
        const { auth, actions, children } = this.props;;
        if (auth.isLoggedIn) {
            actions.getAssessmentRequest();
            actions.getFirstSubsectionRequest();
        }
    }
```

The problem I am having is that the very first time the user logs in the above `componentDidMount` function does not trigger because the header component was already mounted the first time the page was loaded.

I have tried to use `componentDidUpdate` and `componentWillReceiveProps` but they get triggered multiple times and I get request timeout errors.

Any ideas which lifecycle method I could use to achieve this?

Comment: You should use `componentDidUpdate(prevProp,prevState)` and update the `if` statement to compare the current `props`  `auth.isLoggedIn` with the previous `props`

Comment: @Hoyen Your comment is incomplete. His API fetches data which suggests that he will get new data. If he fetches the data in componentDidUpdate; then, he would end up re-rendering. [Chase DeAnda's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49517062/6009304) is a much better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you are on the right path, you should use the `componentWillReceiveProps` lifecycle method. The trick to prevent infinite loops and constantly making requests, you have to perform a check to test whether the props you care about **actually** changed or not:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchData(this.props);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.auth.isLoggedIn !== this.props.auth.isLoggedIn) {
        this.fetchData(nextProps);
    }
}

fetchData(props) {
    const { auth, actions, children } = props;
    if (auth.isLoggedIn) {
        actions.getAssessmentRequest();
        actions.getFirstSubsectionRequest();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would need to know more about how login works. Is it updating state? Or is it updating props? I'm assuming here that it is updating props.

Comment: Yes the check for the `nextProps` is what I missed. This works. Thanks, will accept when it lets me. The login updates the props

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you why it is called multiple times, but I can tell you that it should not matter. The problem is that you're not comparing the props for what has changed. If you do this, the code will behave the way you want:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  const { auth, actions, children } = newProps;
  if (auth.isLoggedIn !== this.props.auth.isLogin) {
    actions.getAssessmentRequest();
    actions.getFirstSubsectionRequest();
  }
}
```

See also the official ReactJS documentation, which states: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops

Hope this helps.